issue in getting total upserted count and total matched count using mongodb bulkwrite updateMany
Below is the bulkWrite method where I am inserting 1000 docs. The issue is I could not able to extract total upsertedCount from the results.
what I get those are individual BulkWriteResult like below for each inserted document
console.log(results) :->

  BulkWriteResult {
     insertedCount: 0,
     matchedCount: 0,
     modifiedCount: 0,
     deletedCount: 0,
     upsertedCount: 1,
     upsertedIds: { '0': new ObjectId('6684fe4d1625ae49f6233577') },
     insertedIds: {}
   }

I would appreciate it if someone came up with the solution.
method->
db.collections.bulkWrite([
     {updateMany :
       {
        "filter": {"name": product.name}, 
        "update": {"$setOnInsert" : {
         name: product.name,
         description: product.description,
         price: product.price,
         category: product.category,

          }},           
         upsert: true
        }
       }
     ],{ ordered: false } )
  .then(results => {
    console.log(results)
  })
 .catch(err=>Error(err))

I searched in MongoDB docs but I could not find any solution in their docs about how to extract the total upsertedCount.

Unless I'm mistaken your bulkWrite only executes a single write operation - an updateMany. Given that no document matched "filter": {"name": product.name} and you had upsert: true set, then one document was added as  specified by your $setOnInsert and confirmed in the upsertedCount: 1, output. Can you explain how you are "inserting 1000 docs".?

the product you are seeing its the each products from products array. There was a for loop which gives each product. Issue is , it does not give total count of all inserted documents. you will get only upsertedCount: 1 against each product.

The docs for the BulkWriteResult class - https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/6.8/classes/BulkWriteResult.html
You should be able to read the upsertedCount property directly like results.upsertedCount

results.upsertedCount gives only count of one product. How to sum them up. For example if I inserted 10 products then results would be like below->                                                                            { results.upsertedCount = 1} ,    {results.upsertedCount = 1}, {results.upsertedCount = 1}   .....so on                                                                                                                                 How to get the total  upsertedCount for all 10 products

Are you calling 'bulkWrite' with a single updateMany document?

There is a limitation of  characters in stackoverflow , so whole code was not shared instead important portion of the code was shared above.
Yes I am doing bulkwrite of many documents. .  product refers in updateMany function is nothing but each product in a products array I hope you understand.    Insertion occurs fine. issue -> could not able to retrieve total number of upsertedCount . I tried with bulkWrite insertMany too , there also i am not getting total number of insertedCounts instead getting each insertedCounts = 1

I ran the following from mongosh: test> let op1=[], op2=[]; for(i=0;i<100;i++){let op={updateMany:{filter:{i,i},update:{$setOnInsert:{test:true}},upsert:true}}; if (i % 3 == 0){op1.push(op)}; op2.push(op); }; let res1=db.bulktest.bulkWrite(op1,{ordered:false}); let res2=db.bulktest.bulkWrite(op2,{ordered:false});print("res1:",res1.upsertedCount," res2:",res2.upsertedCount), Result was: res1: 34  res2: 66.  I suspect the problem in your code is not the bulkWrite function itself, but how it is called.  You might enable auditing to catch these commands as they are sent to the server.
